# Installing Ubuntu on ThinkStation D20

Tags: drivers, windows, windows-7, hardware, compatibility

I have a Lenovo ThinkStation D20 machine and am hoping to install Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04. Before I do, I want to make sure that the hardware will support it. I don't see this specific machine listed in the supported hardware catalog https://certification.ubuntu.com/server/ . Can anyone help? Just to add, this machine originally was built to run Windows 7

Comment: Don't trust us - try it. Boot from a Ubuntu system on USB, and select "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: I've got a Toshiba which is running with an Ubuntu 16.04, and it's working fine (and as you can see, there is not at all Toshiba in the list of vendor, lol), and your link is about UbuntuServer, not the desktop Ubuntu

Comment: Yup. Try the LiveUSB.